# How to pass list through node.js callbacks into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, database

Task: using node and mongodb, given a list, [{a:1},{b:2},...,{n:x}], I want to query the database for each item in the list, and if the item is absent, insert it into the database.

I ran into an unrelated problem doing this. I do a `find().toArray()`
for each item in the list, and if the `arraylen != 0`, push the item to a second list, called dict.

Problem is that when I pass dict into the callback function, in the callback function, dict is empty, even though I pushed three items on it.

I tried printing out dict but each time I push something to it I get the following output:

```
Connected correctly to server
[]

pushing

[ undefined ]

pushing

[ undefined, undefined ]

pushing

[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Code:

```
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

var d1 = [{'a': 1}, 
    {'a': 2},
    {'a': 3}];
//console.log(d1);

var f = function(db,dict2, callback) {
    console.log(dict2);
    for(var i = 0, len = dict2.length; i < len; i++){
        db.collection('documents').insert(dict2[i], function(){});
    }
    callback();
}

var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {

  var collection = db.collection('documents');
    var dict1 = [];
    //db.collection('documents').insert({'a':1}, function(err, result) {});
    for(var i = 0, len = d1.length; i < len; i++){
        var cursor = collection.find(d1[i]).toArray(function(err, ar){
            if(ar.length == 0){
                console.log('pushing');
                dict1.push(d1[i]);
                console.log(dict1);
            } 
        });
    }
    callback(dict1);    
}


// Connection URL

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    insertDocuments(db, function(dict) {
        f(db,dict, function(){
            db.close();
        });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your `callback(dict)` BEFORE any of your `collection.find()` operations have completed.  Thus, the `dict` object is empty when you call it.

Those are `collection.find()` operations are asynchronous and complete some time later while your `for` loop executes synchronously and then you do `callback(dict)` before they have completed.

There are numerous ways to approach this type of problem.  My preferred method would be to use promises and use `Promise.all()` or Bluebird's `Promise.map()` to know when all your async operations are done, but a method with the least rewrite of your code is to just use a counter to count when all the operations are done and then call the callback.

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

var d1 = [{'a': 1}, 
    {'a': 2},
    {'a': 3}];
//console.log(d1);

var f = function(db,dict2, callback) {
    console.log(dict2);
    for(var i = 0, len = dict2.length; i < len; i++){
        db.collection('documents').insert(dict2[i], function(){});
    }
    callback();
}

var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {

  var collection = db.collection('documents');
    var dict1 = [];
    var cntr = 0;
    //db.collection('documents').insert({'a':1}, function(err, result) {});
    for(var i = 0, len = d1.length; i < len; i++){
        let index = i;
        var cursor = collection.find(d1[i]).toArray(function(err, ar){
            if(ar.length == 0){
                console.log('pushing');

                dict1.push(d1[index]);
                console.log(dict1);
            } 
            ++cntr;
            // if all the requests are done, then call the callback
            // with the results we have accumulated
            if (cntr === len) {
                callback(dict);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

FYI, the MongoDB now supports using promises to interact with the async operations which would likely make this code a bit more flexible.  Here's a version using promises from the `.find()` operation:

```
var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {

    var collection = db.collection('documents');
    var dict1 = [];
    var promises = [];
    d1.forEach(function(item) {
        promises.push(collection.find(item).toArray().then(function(ar) {
            if (ar.length == 0){
                console.log('pushing');
                dict1.push(item);
                console.log(dict1);
            } 
        }));
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        callback(null, dict1);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        callback(err);
    });
}
```

And, note this version changes the signature of the callback to include a possible error as the first argument so that you can do error handling (you should add error handling to the first version too).

Comment: @bat - I've edited my code to fix another error of yours.  You can't reference `i` in the `collection.find()` callback because the `for` loop has already moved on to the end before the callback is called.  You can either change the iteration to `.forEach()` which will save the index for you separate for each invocation of the loop or use a block scoped variable with `let` like I show in my answer now.

Comment: @Bat - I changed the second version of my code to use `.forEach()`.

Comment: it worked! thank you. how did you learn that you could use .then() with .find()? I'd like to find a good reference book, if possible

Comment: @bat - I've seen it in other posts here on stack overflow and it's in the [doc here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find).